# ECS task shuts down before all containers complete. How to prevent that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using dockerized python code which does some processing and then completes. Currently hosted on ECS with Fargate. The problem is, when I include more than one container in a task, it seems that the task stops after one of the container completes. Any idea how I can prevent that from happening?
Thanks

Comment: Have you set up any dependency management in your task definition? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_dependson

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the issue. The problem was with the 'essential' container. The whole container shutdowns when the essential container is completed. This was solved when the dependencies was set up accordingly.